# which storage is suitable to store many sets of tables of same schema?

Tags: database, database-design

I use a table to store various classifications of all words in the dictionary.

It looks like this:

```
word     category   origin-language
-------  ---------  ---------------
happy    adjective  English
bonjour  greeting   French
...
```

from a set of classifications, I am able to produce a number.
I want to find a set which produces a minimum, so I want to store many sets of such classifications (each is a table) together with their respective numbers in a storage.

What kind of storage is suitable for this task? I don't think relational database is suitable, since there is no datatype for tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a single table like yours plus a column to identify the classification set:

Classification (ClassificationSet, Word, Category, OiginLanguage) KEY ???

Several DBMSs do have a type for tables and some (e.g. Oracle) allow nested tables. I don't think that's relevant to your problem. It's usually more straightforward to find an equivalent model without nested tables.

Comment: I'm afraid that makes the table huge, I have 1million words in the dictionary, and there are about 100 different sets of classifications.

Comment: 100 million rows is not huge. Any of the popular SQL DBMSs will easily cope with data of that size. Separating it into different tables as you suggested wouldn't make the data any smaller.

Answer (score 0):

my current thinking is that I store all such tables under a different database schema, name them table_1, table_2, ...,
and create a new table:

```
 database_obj       outcome
----------------   ---------
 table_1            12.3
 table_2            -6.4
 .....
```

Comment: IMO it's a terrible idea: You will either have to repeat query, constraint and other logic or make it much more complicated than it needs to be (because it has to access many tables instead of just 1). Queries will be more complex and perform poorly. Administration and change management will be harder. Greater potential for inconsistent data. I can't think of any good reason for creating 100 identical tables when just one will do.